# Long text within a bootstrap column affects following columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tuBKeuLN5OGmKjiSG8n1?p=preview) demonstrates the problem I am seeing. i added a background color to highlight the issue

**Please note** , in order to see the issue you will need to view the plunkr in its preview popout window - or have the preview panel at least 800px wide. See the image below for the button to click, if you've never done this before. Once popped out, make the screen a little bigger.

[image]

Essentially, what I am finding is if i have, say 4 `col-sm-6' they normally sit side by side, giving me 2 columns and 2 rows.

This is all ok until there is some long text in one of the child elements. This then pushes the following cells out of alignment.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but it's eluding me... Any thoughts?

And the code in the Plunkr is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">A really long company name fs df sd fsdfsdfsdf sdf s df sd f sdf sd f sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Break it into 2 rows. There should only be 12 columns worth of elements in each row.

Comment: Why the downvote? Man its just stupid when it comes without reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with two row

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Company</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">A really long company name fs df sd fsdfsdfsdf sdf s df sd f sdf sd f sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" >

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">XYZ</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">Something</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Balls... thanks. Couldn't see the wood for the trees.. :D (will mark as answer once allowed)

Comment: Thanks Darren me too somtime don'see the right question because obscured by detail and multitasking problem solving ... good work